# Why does `binary operation argument type newval is not compatible with type string` appear

Tags: webstorm

I have the following code and inside of it the WebStorm inspection `Binary operation argument type newVal is not compatible with type string` appears:

[image]

I'm wondering why

Full module code:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var ng = require('angular');
    require('../ngModule').directive('downloadFile', ['$parse', 'auth.authService', function ($parse, authService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var getter = $parse(attrs.downloadFile);

                scope.$watch(getter, function (path) {
                    if (path !== "") {
                        var form = document.createElement("form");
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");

                        form.method = "POST";
                        form.action = path;

                        element1.value = authService.getToken();
                        element1.name = "Authorization";
                        form.appendChild(element1);

                        element.append(form);

                        form.submit();
                        element.empty();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Please can you provide the full code snippet as text? Do you use JSDoc to annotate your code?

Comment: @lena, yes, sure, I've updated my answer. No, I almost don't use `JSDoc`, occasionally in some files

Comment: thanks:) No warnings are reported for me when using your code... there must be some other files involved. Try ctrl+clicking on 'path' - where does WebStorm navigate? Also, try invalidating caches - does the problem persist?

Comment: @lena, thanks, invalidating cache helped. Do you know what this inspection is about?

Comment: normally this inspection checks if called function parameters and return types are correct; in your case it (mistakenly) thinks that 'path' parameter can't be compared to string. But this violation is a result of broken indexes, so make no sense

Answer (score 11):

AngularJS's JSDoc definition makes WebStorm think the `path` argument is a boolean.

You can make WebStorm stop complaining by adding your own JSDoc:

`if (path !== /** @type {boolean} */"") {`

Comment: thanks, can you please point to that gist of code where Angular's JSDoc states that `path` is boolean? Here is the definition for the listener: `@param {function(newVal, oldVal, scope)} listener Callback called whenever the value` - no mentioning of a boolean type