# this.category.ageCategory !== 0 return false because of type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a condition that fails all the times:

```
this.category.ageCategory !== 5
```

if I change `!==` with `!=`, it will work

My Category Object:

```
export class Category {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ageCategory: number;
  ...
}
```

My Form:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="ageCategory" id="ageCategory" [(ngModel)]="category.ageCategory">
     <option *ngFor="let ageCat of ageCategories" [value]="ageCat.id">
          {{ageCat.text | translate }}
     </option>
</select>
```

In fact, if I debug, I can see that `ageCategory` is a string `"5"`

Why is ageCategory a string ?

Should I use `parseInt` for all my variables :(

Comment: can you try this.category.ageCategory < 1...let me know that works for you or not

Comment: I have 5 differents values, not just 0, so, it will no be very good I think

Comment: this.category.ageCategory !== 0  is condition is in html or in ts ?

Comment: The accepted answer is a bit of a workaround. You can just use `ngValue` instead, which will allow the value to be numeric. e.g. `[ngValue]="ageCat.id"`.

Comment: You are right, this is the answer I was looking for. Please put it as answer, and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-select-controls-with-form-directives) for exactly this purpose. It allows you to specify a value that is *not* a string when model-binding. In your example, all you'd need to change is the following:

```html
<option *ngFor="let ageCat of ageCategories" [ngValue]="ageCat.id">
    {{ageCat.text | translate }}
</option>
```

It's as simple as changing from `[value]` to `[ngValue]` and gives you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work enclose it with quotes since its a string

```
this.category.ageCategory !== "0"
```

Comment: I get `binary operation argument type string is not compatible with type "0"`

Comment: are you using webstorm?

Comment: its a known issue with websotm, but theroratically above should work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721724/why-does-binary-operation-argument-type-newval-is-not-compatible-with-type-stri

Comment: ohh, OK, but really, I'm dealing with number, and that is what I should be handling. Isn't it a way to simply manipulate numbers ? why is this value converted to string if even in my model, it is defined as number

Comment: anything on the template is a string, even if the daatype is a number

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to number right when you select it. Something like following

```
<select class="form-control" name="ageCategory" id="ageCategory" [(ngModel)]="category.ageCategory"  (ngModelChange)="onChangeSelection($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let ageCat of ageCategories" [value]="ageCat.id">
          {{ageCat.text | translate }}
     </option>
</select>
```

And in your Component:

```
onChangeSelection(ageCategory) {
    this.category.ageCategory = parseInt(ageCategory);
}
```

**Update**

Select tags always output in string so you need to convert it to number for your use. what ever the way either right when you select like above method or compare it with stringified number.

Comment: ok, but it would give me 1 extra function for each variable. kind of annoying no ?

Comment: it won't affect the performance so you can use it. because select always return string values even if you give them number in option value

Comment: ohh, OK, this was the info I was looking for. I will still prefer the @Sajeetharan answer, but please include this fact in your answer so that I can upvote it