# How can I check the value of this.state with an if statement and not console.log()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I want to check the values of `this.state.cityCodeval` and `this.state.idVal` using an `if` statement inside the `displayName()` method so it can display what's inside the `return()` if the values inputted by the user are correct.

In my `Webstorm` IDE, I get a warning that says:

```
Binary operation argument type string is not compatible with type string
```

Which makes me believe I'm checking for their values the wrong way.

I know I could just do `console.log(this.state.cityCodeval);` or `console.log(this.state.idVal);`, but I need to check for what the user input is.

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionType from '../../store/actions/actions';

class SearchArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            flag: false,
            idVal: '',
            cityCodeval: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleArticleId = this.handleArticleId.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("IDValue --> " + this.state.idVal);

        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(this.state.idVal);
        this.setState({flag: true});
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.cityCodeReducerRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleArticleId = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({idVal: event.target.value});
    }

    displayName = () => {
        if(this.state.cityCodeval === 'nyc' && this.state.idVal === '1') {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>author name: {this.state.authorNameValue}</p>
                    <p>article text: {this.state.storyTextValue}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input onChange={this.handleArticleId} value={this.state.idVal} placeholder="article id"/>
                    <button type="submit" value="Search">Submit</button>
                    {this.state.flag ? this.displayName() : null}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cityCodeValue: state.cityCodeValue.cityCodeValue,
        authorNameValue: state.authorNameValue.authorNameValue,
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        cityCodeReducerRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE, value}),
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchArticle);
```

Comment: This sounds similar: "Why does `binary operation argument type newval is not compatible with type string` appear" - https://stackoverflow.com/q/32721724/2430549

Answer (score 0):

You should still return null; as a safe clause just in case your condition doesn't match.

```
 displayName = () => {
    if(this.state.cityCodeval === 'nyc' && this.state.idVal === '1') {
       console.log(this.state.cityCodeval); // console it here
       console.log(this.state.idVal); // console it here
       return (
         <div>
           <p>author name: {this.state.authorNameValue}</p>
           <p>article text: {this.state.storyTextValue}</p>
         </div>
       );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also now, in your render method you can do this.

```
{this.state.flag && this.displayName()}
```

This means that if the `flag` variable is true, call `displayName` it then executes the function. If you first condition matches it will return that otherwise it will return null;

Previously in your current code if the `flag` variable was true and it executed the function `displayName` where the `if` condition didn't meet. This caused an error because it had nothing to return.

Comment: I understand what you said.  I tried it, but it's not working.  Nothing's being displayed.

Comment: try consoling this.state at top of your displayName function just above the if statement, what is the result that you get?

Comment: The reason I assume nothing is being displayed is because your `if(this.state.cityCodeval === 'nyc' && this.state.idVal === '1') {}` is never true.

Comment: Yeah that was my original question.  I want to check the values of the states via if condition, but I'm struggling as to how to achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the values of the states? If you don't want to log it in the console, how about just output it with `{this.state.flag.toString()}`, for example, in your component?